# How to remove duplicate rows from a file?

Tags: shell, shell-script

File,

```
TABLE1  
-------  
1234

TABLE1  
-------  
9555  

TABLE1  
-------  
87676  

TABLE1
-------  
2344
```

I want the output like

```
TABLE1  
-------  
1234
9555  
87676
2344
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one liner, using `sed` and `awk` :

```
sed '/^$/d' filename | awk '!a[$1]++'
```

Combination of `grep` and `awk` :

```
grep . filename | awk '!a[$1]++'
```

As @[cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas) suggested, You can do that in single `awk` command also.

```
awk '!x[$1]++ && ! /^[[:blank:]]*$/' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk '!x[$1]++' file > file_new`

While trying this command, I was getting one extra new line in the file you have given.

I modified this to `awk '!x[$1]++' file | sed  '/^$/d' > file_new`, which should solve your problem for this case.

Comment: how is that any different to @arzyfex's earlier answer?  anyway, in both answers, neither `sed` nor `grep` is even necessary: `awk '!x[$1]++ && ! /^[[:blank:]]*$/' filename.txt`

Comment: @cas Thank you. I had forgot to update, anyway updated my answer as per your suggestion.

Comment: @cas: I think, I was typing while arzyfex posted the answer :P Anyways, Yes, only one awk will be enough. Reason is Awk and Sed basically accomplish same task with awk having some deeper options for text processing, But if sed can accomplish your task, I will refrain from using awk as awk processes 69 million characters  per second while sed processes 82 million character per second, hence sed being faster than awk.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old thread, I would like to contribute this answer that uses only a single sed command:

```
sed '1,2p;/^[[:digit:]]/!d;' file
```

It keeps the two first lines (the heading and underline), then deletes every line that doesn't start with a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `uniq`, you can remove duplicate entries. Like :

```
cat file | sort -r | uniq
```

But in this specific case is not producing exactly the expected result as the file must be sorted for `uniq` to work - it will only detect duplicate lines if they are adjacent.
Another solution would be to read file and skip the lines containing `TABLE` or `----` (except first occurrence) :

```
count_t=0
count_d=0
while read line; do 
  if [[ $line == "TABLE"* ]] ; then  
    if [[ $count_t -eq 0 ]]; then 
      ((count_t++)) 
    else
      continue 
    fi 
  fi
  if [[ $line == "-----"* ]] ; then  
    if [[ $count_d -eq 0 ]]; then 
      ((count_d++)) 
    else
      continue 
    fi
  fi
  echo $line
done < file
```

The `awk` and `sed` solutions posted by others are better though.

Comment: colud you please tell me what is the command? @mazs

Comment: I have tried cat File | uniq > File1.. but its giving me the same output as original file

Comment: yes I want this actually..."Another solution would be to read file and skip the lines containing TABLE or ---- (except first occurrence)" ... then what will be the command? I have trie 'cat file | egrep -v "TABLE|-------"

Comment: You can not write it on the same file. You need to change the output file name

Comment: I cannot come up with a one liner, but i'll post a small script

Answer (score 0):

I usually use sort and uniq together to get rid of duplicates like this:

```
    cat file | sort | uniq
```

However, with your input, it will end up like this:

```
    -------
    1234
    2344
    87676
    9555
    TABLE1
```

This command removes all but the numbers and adds the header afterwards:

```
    cat file | grep '^[[:digit:]]*$'| grep -v '^$' |sed '1iTABLE1\n-------'
```

and gives you this result:

```
    TABLE1
    -------
    1234
    9555
    87676
    2344
```